# How do I check if property exists before using RXJS pluck()?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, rxjs-observables

The following code works fine if the "canLogin" property exists.

```
this.canLogin$ = this.permissions$.pipe(pluck('canLogin'));
```

If the property doesn't exist, I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'canLogin' of undefined

How can I check for null or return null if the property doesn't exist?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
this.canLogin$ = this.permissions$.pipe(pluck('canLogin')) || of(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not because the property doesn't exist. The error is because `permissions$` emits `undefined` and that can't have any property.

So you can do something like for example:

```
this.canLogin$ = this.permissions$
  .pipe(
    map(obj => obj || {}),
    pluck('canLogin'),
  );
```